# Intellij Idea build jar file without Infra.properties file Needed

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, netbeans-8

[Please Find the project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjLQb.png)

I am trying to create the executable jar file for the sales order module as per the project structure. while building the jar, pointing to the sales order main class in execution package.

Also, I have added additional folders as a resource file. Infra.properties file in the project structure builds along with jar file. how to restrict that file, want use that file separately should not build in jar file itself

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear what build tool you are using.

If you are using *IntelliJ IDEA* specific build, then do next:

1. Open **File** > **Settings...**
2. Go to **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Compiler** > **Excludes**
3. Add entry for the file you want to exclude, e.g.:
   [image]

---

If you are using *Maven* specific build, then add exclude section to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/infra.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Pattern here might be more specific of course.